# How to change opacity of Navigation Link when clicked xcode / Swift UI

Tags: xcode, user-interface, swiftui

I have a Navigation Link set up with an image and by default when the user presses the Navigation Link, the image is reduced to around 30-40% opacity.

I'm wondering how to prevent this from happening and how to set the opacity to whatever I need it to be.

My code:

```
NavigationLink(destination:
    PostPageView()
    .navigationBarTitle(Text("Post"), displayMode: .inline)
    .foregroundColor(Color("blackAndWhite"))
  ){
    Image("partyyy").resizable().frame(height: 300)

  }
```

Image with example you can see below.
Appreciate your help!

[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgqb0.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own button style and add it to the NavigationLink.

`.buttonStyle(MyButtonStyle())`

Create a Struct for the custom style like this:

```
    struct MyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    public func makeBody(configuration: MyButtonStyle.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 1 : 1)

            // You can also add other animated properties
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.8 : 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot!